# AnsiString in C++?

Tags: c++, delphi, visual-c++

Is there a type like `AnsiString(65001)` in C++ like there is in Delphi? I would like to use it for interop between an Application and DLL.

Comment: I guess that denotes a narrow-characters string in Windows codepage 65001, which is the badly half-supported UTF-8 codepage. Just use `std::string` and remember it's UTF-8.

Comment: @Deduplicator Are you sure? http://pastebin.com/siaV0ytN

Comment: @JohnLewis not sure what you're asking but your snippet works just fine : http://ideone.com/d5ZAwC

Comment: As I said, MS has a hate-love-hate relationship with UTF-8. Somehow, they must justify having ended up with UTF-16 ;-) You could try the `u8`-prefix for the string-literal...

Comment: @tux3 I get `warning C4566: character represented by universal-character-name '\u7392' cannot be represented in the current code page (1252)` O.o ?

Comment: @Deduplicator: In what way is `std::string` UTF-8?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: It is if you say it is. Otherwise, it is not. How do you read in any of my previous comments a guarantee that it is, instead of a caution that it is whatever the programmer decides to make it?

Comment: @Deduplicator: _"Just use `std::string` and remember it's UTF-8"_  ← You said that `std::string` is UTF-8. It's not UTF-8. It's not _not_ UTF-8 either, but it's not UTF-8.

Comment: You should use `std::string` for 8-bit character strings, and you can convert to or from `AnsiString` via both's `c_ptr()`. The key is that `AnsiString<>` is aware of what code page its contents are, and `std::string` isn't; you should store that information as well. A composite type that contains a codepage, a `std::string`, and methods to convert would be a good approach.

Comment: *How much* "like" `AnsiString` do you need this hypothetical C++ type to be? There are many aspects to that type. You mention interop — does that mean the application is in Delphi, and you want to write a DLL in C++ that receives and returns `AnsiString` values? That's a fool's errand. Or do you mean you want a C++-only type that automatically converts between code pages when assigned to cooperative types? You could rig something up for that. Or do you just mean you want a string type that can hold UTF-8 characters? Please [edit] your question to be more precise about what you really need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++Builder specifically (which uses the same RTL as Delphi), there is the `AnsiStringT` templated class that provides the same functionality as Delphi's `AnsiString(N)` type:

```
template <unsigned short CP>
class RTL_DELPHIRETURN AnsiStringT : public AnsiStringBase
```

Where `CP` is the desired codepage.

The RTL's `UTF8String` and `RawByteString` types are just aliases for this functionality:

Delphi:

```
type
  UTF8String = type AnsiString(65001);
  RawByteString = type AnsiString($ffff);
```

C++Builder:

```
typedef AnsiStringT<65001> UTF8String;
typedef AnsiStringT<65535> RawByteString;
```

Comment: There is no such equivalent functionality in other C++ compilers. You have to use explicit conversions in your code via `MultiByteToWideChar()`/`WideCharToMultiByte()`, `std::codecvt`, etc (which you could use to write your own `AnsiStringT`-like wrapper class, if so desired).

Comment: I'll have to port the `AnsiString` to `Visual C++` then :)

Comment: @John This answer doesn't seem to address your question which was about MSVC. I don't know why you accepted the answer. Porting the Emba rtl is probably not the way to go.

Answer (score 4):

`std::string` is guaranteed to act as a container of `char`s, and `char` is guaranteed to be exactly 1 byte, that seems to match the description of an AnsiString.

Although note that you can always force some multi-byte Unicode characters in a std::string if you really want to, there's no compiler-enforced guarantee that each logical character be encoded by 1 byte. There is no easy way to enforce that in C++, short of writing your own class.

For interoperability, you might want to use a raw cstring (`char*`) though.